# Customise the layout of Parse PFLoginViewController using Storyboards?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, xcode-storyboard, pfloginviewcontroller

I'm building an app using parse and I was wondering if it's possible to customise look & layout of the PFLoginViewController visually using storyboards? I know it's possible to subclass it and customise it using code but I would prefer to do it visually if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do it visually. However, you can make your own custom class by going on storyboard and making it like this :

[image: Custom Login View Controller from a Navigation Controller]

The Code would then look something like this for parse:

import UIKit
import Parse

class CustomLoginViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

var actInd : UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 150, 150)) as UIActivityIndicatorView

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.actInd.center = self.view.center
    self.actInd.hidesWhenStopped = true
    self.actInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    view.addSubview(self.actInd)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

// MARK: Actions

@IBAction func loginAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    var username = self.usernameField.text
    var password = self.passwordField.text

    if (username.utf16Count < 4 || password.utf16Count < 5) {

        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Invalid", message: "Username must be greater then 4 and Password must be greater then 5", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()

    }else {

        self.actInd.startAnimating()

        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username, password: password, block: { (user, error) -> Void in

            self.actInd.stopAnimating()

            if ((user) != nil) {

                var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Success", message: "Logged In", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()

            }else {

                var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Error", message: "\(error)", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()

            }

        })

    }

}

@IBAction func signUpAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("signUp", sender: self)

}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, makes sense!